# What's that green line when I perform a ls -la?

Tags: command-line, mount

I am not an expert on Ubuntu, so this is probably a very basic question.

When I open a terminal and perform a ls -la in a directory, I get:

```
jverstrynge@devjverstrynge:/home/httpd$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  6 root     root       91 Dec 11 14:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root     root       56 Dec 10 11:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 tfr      tfr         6 Oct 22 13:49 softgallery-future
drwxr-xr-x 11 tfr      tfr      4096 Oct 22 14:06 softgallery-old
drwxrwxrwx 10 www-data www-data  138 Dec 11 12:37 softgallery2
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data  149 Feb  9  2015 subscription
```

The `softgallery2` line is displayed in green. What is the meaning? Does it mean it's a mount? How can I check this?

Comment: Basically, it means it's read-writeable by other users, but head over to the duplicate question to learn more

Comment: executable or recognized data file.